# PushViewController don't apper in UITabbar using iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

- I have little problem with `pushViewController`.
- I have `tabBar` with two tabs.
- When I clicked on button in menu I get `UINavigationController` and put it to root controller.

---

```
navigationController = (DEMONavigationController *)[[MyManager sharedManager] getRefToMap];
            MapaZPunktami * mapa = (MapaZPunktami *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
self.frostedViewController.contentViewController = navigationController;
```

It works fine.

But when I need `pushViewController` as:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController: myController animated:YES];
```

- Push works, because on `navigation bar` I can see title and backButton, but old `UiView` stay on center screen. It isn't replace with new uiview...

Screens:

[image: Before clicked]
[image: After clicked]

Comment: I have no idea what this line part does: `navigationController = (DEMONavigationController *)[[MyManager sharedManager] getRefToMap];
            MapaZPunktami * mapa = (MapaZPunktami *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
self.frostedViewController.contentViewController = navigationController;`

Comment: in this line I get reference to another UiNavigationController and change base uiNavigationController with reference